# How to force same step on both y axes

Tags: highcharts

LinkedTo does not solve the issue.

**Example:**

Let's say that first series has data ranging from 23 to -82. 
Second series has data ranging between 82 and -23

In that case, to have same scale we need to put range: +40 to -100 for the first series and +100 to -40 for the second series.

Both ranges have same net range of 140 units, and a readable 20 point step.

Is it possible to achieve this in highstocks?

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/4/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart',{
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Primary'
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: false,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary'
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 0
        },
    }],

    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [-77.0, -82, -59.5, -44.5, -28.2, -13, -5.2, 16.5, 23, 8.3, 3.9, -9.6]
    }, {
        yAxis:1,
        name: 'New York',
        data: [64.0, 82, 40.5, 14.5, 8.2, 13, -23.2, -13, -1, 29.3, 14.9, 1.1]
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: You might be looking for `alignTicks: false`

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, it works correctly with supplied data but with other data I'm getting disjoined axes, with different step values (10 units on one, 5 units on 2nd)... I still want ticks to be aligned on both axes

Comment: Please provide some data that does not work.

Comment: this gives a step of 25 on one side and 10 on the other: http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/5/

Comment: You can simple set tickInterval, but it doesn't look good in the above demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/8/ I would just use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickPositioner) instead. Calculate ticks on your own: http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/9/

Comment: How would  you set tickinterval dynamically? (so that when you change the view from YTD to All it changes too). In your second example it doesn't work for me, the axes are disjoined...

Comment: For setting `tickInterval` you can use `axis.update()` but it will create performance issues. Regarding `tickPositioner` it's just an example how to use it, not a solution (so this is a comment, not an answer..). In my opinion there should be the same number of ticks, not the same tick-range. What ticks you expect to see for chart with data: 0-100 and 0-1 ? Step=0.25 will work for 0-1 range, but it will be a mess in 0-100 range..

Comment: We can assume that data will always be within a similar range. the idea is to see the increase/decrease on one series and compare it with increase/decrease on another on net basis

Comment: So in that case, this would be enough: http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/12/ - I modified data to be more or less the same range. Anyway, have you considered using [`compare`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.compare) option?

Comment: for one series 800-200 range and second -400 to 0 it uses different steps... 200 on one and 100 on the other...

Comment: In that case, first axis has 600units and second has 400units. If you set 100 tickInterval, then one axis will have 6 ticks and second 4 ticks. That will **missalign** axes. Whatever interval you will set that will **missalign** axes. Anyway, you need to write logic you want to use in tickPositioner..

Comment: My example with your datesets: http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/13/ - I'm not saying my solution is perfect, may need some polishing, but it's a good starting point, I think.

Comment: Pawel I got it to work. One thing: what's the default behaviour of tickpositioner? I'm instantiating charts from javascript, and want to enable my custom positioner in some, and default in others.

Comment: there is an issue if first axis has less ticks than 2nd one... because we can't refer to the 2nd one in tickspositioner of the 1st